# Is there a way to force an envelope in docusign api to be wet signature only?

Tags: json, docusignapi

I'm trying to create an envelope that will only allow for a wet signature using the docusign api. Is there any functionality for this? I haven't been able to find it where I've looked. I know there's an enableWetSign property, but that still allows for Esign. If somebody could help me with this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way -- either using the API or just via account configuration using the DocuSign web console UI -- to REQUIRE a WET signature and explicitly DISALLOW an ELECTRONIC signature for an Envelope.  As you point out (by mentioning the **enableWetSign** property) -- you can control whether or not wet signing is allowed,...but there is no comparable property to control whether or not electronically signing is allowed.

Answer (score 7):

DocuSign has since added this feature, so at the time Kim was correct, however, this now can be done per recipient as shown below:

Keep in mind the following as brought up in follow-on answers:

- DocuSign **Support** or **account representative** must enable this feature for your DocuSign account first before it will work.
- needs to be used with a composite template (shown below) vs a simple template referenced by `templateid` (Thanks - Tom Copeland)
- Set the **enableWetSign** property at the envelope info
- Set the **[requireSignOnPaper](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/#/definitions/signer)** property for each recipient.

  `POST /restapi/v2/accounts/[youraccountid]/envelopes HTTP/1.1
  Host: demo.docusign.net
  X-DocuSign-Authentication: [removed]
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA
  Accept: application/json`

`

```
--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
  "enableWetSign": "true",
  "enforceSignerVisibility": "true",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "recipientId": "1",
                "name": "Your Email (Sees all)",
                "email": "yourgmail+Test1@gmail.com",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "Sign1",
                      "tabLabel": "Sign Here 1"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "recipientId": "2",
                "name": "Your Email (sees all but page 2)",
                "email": "yourgmail@gmail.com",
                "requireSignOnPaper": "true",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "Sign2",
                      "tabLabel": "Sign Here 2"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "carbonCopies": [
              {
                "email": "yourgmail+Testcc@gmail.com",
                "name": "Your Email (see all but 3 document)",
                "excludedDocuments": [
                  "3"
                ],
                "recipientId": "3",
                "routingOrder": "3"
              },
              {
                "email": "yourgmail+Testcc1@gmail.com",
                "name": "Your Email (see all)",
                "recipientId": "4",
                "routingOrder": "4"
              }
            ]
          },
          "documents": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "name": "test1.txt"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "2",
              "name": "test2.txt"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "3",
              "name": "test3.txt"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailBlurb": "Test for CEFTAF DocVis ForceSign on Paper",
  "emailSubject": "Test for CEFTAF DocVis ForceSign on Paper",
  "status": "sent",
}   

--AAA
Content-Type: application/txt
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.txt"; documentid=1

Test Document 1 

Sign1 Here _______________________________



Sign2 Here _______________________________


--AAA
Content-Type: application/txt
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test2.txt"; documentid=2

Test Document 2

Sign1 Here _______________________________

--AAA
Content-Type: application/txt
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test3.txt"; documentid=3

Test Document 3

No Tabs for anyone means visible to all by default unless excluded

--AAA--
```

`

Comment: Note: You will need to talk to your account manager or support to enable the features for this: Document Visibility and Enable allow and require Wet Sign.

Answer (score 0):

Specific recipient element is "requireSignOnPaper".

Answer (score 0):

Note that `requireSignOnPaper` needs to be used with a composite template; it won't have any effect if used with a simple `templateId` parameter.